# JavaScript how to use for each

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="errorTable" class="alert alert-danger alert-warning">

        <!--    Validating City START -->

            <div id="divname">
             <tr>
                <td width="3"></td>
                <td width="23"><span class="table_row_error_text"><img id="imgsum" src="/images/error.gif" class="image" style="display: none;" ></span> </td>
                <td width="5"></td>
                <td><span class="table_row_error_text"> <span id="errorsum" /></span> </td>
        </tr>
        </div>

        <!-- Validating City ENDS -->
        <!--    Validating Zip Code START -->

            <div id="divtype">
              <tr>
                <td width="3"></td>
                <td width="23"><span class="table_row_error_text"><img id="imgdesc" src="/images/error.gif" class="image" style="display: none;" ></span> </td>
                <td width="5"></td>
                <td><span class="table_row_error_text"> <span id="errordesc" /></span> </td>
        </tr>
        </div>

        <!-- Validating Zip Code  ENDS -->

    </table> Summary:
    <input id="summaryOfAlert" type="text" />

    <br>
    <br> Description:
    <input id="textarea3" type="text" />

    <br>
    <br> Save:
    <input type="submit" onClick="return validateText()" /> </body>

<script>
    function validateText() {
        alert("Hi");
        var summary = document.getElementById("summaryOfAlert").value;
        var description = document.getElementById("textarea3").value;
        var letters = /^[A-Za-z0-9._\-,\s]+$/;
        var j;
        j = 0;

        if (summary != "") {
            if (!summary.match(letters)) {
                document.getElementById('errorsum').innerHTML = "In Summary Please Enter Only A-Za-z0-9-,_.";
                document.getElementById("divname").style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById("imgsum").style.display = 'block';
                j++;
            }
        }

        if (description != "") {
            if (!description.match(letters)) {
                document.getElementById('errordesc').innerHTML = "In Description Please Enter Only A-Za-z0-9-,_.";
                document.getElementById("divtype").style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById("imgdesc").style.display = 'block';
                j++;
            }
        }

        if (j == 0) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Above is a html/javascript code which I have developed for front end validation for special characters. it is working fine but my problem is whenever I entered special chars like <>%&(^ in both text fields and after submitting it is showing error message like as shown
        In Summary Please Enter Only A-Za-z0-9-,*.
        In Description Please Enter Only A-Za-z0-9-,*.

But when I removed special chars in one of the text fields and submitting the values again both error messages are displaying instead of only one error message

Comment: First of all your html structure is all wrong. You cannot start a div after tr, it should be in td and if you do close it before you close tr and not after it.

Comment: Ok I will check it
Thanks for your post

Comment: @VenkatKrishna - You should use **`else`** part to hide you message

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the messages but you are not hiding them anywhere. Try this:

```
if(!summary.match(letters)) {

    document.getElementById('errorsum').innerHTML="In Summary Please Enter Only A-Za-z0-9-,_.";

    document.getElementById("divname").style.display='block';

    document.getElementById("imgsum").style.display='block';

    j++;
} else {
    document.getElementById('errorsum').innerHTML="";

    document.getElementById("divname").style.display='none';

    document.getElementById("imgsum").style.display='none';
}
```

And the same things for description. You could also make it a function so you don't have to write it twice.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code** you should use `else` part to hide you message

```
function validateText() {
    alert("Hi");

var summary         = document.getElementById("summaryOfAlert").value;

var description     = document.getElementById("textarea3").value;

var letters         = /^[A-Za-z0-9._\-,\s]+$/;

var j;

j = true;

if(summary!="") {   
        if(!summary.match(letters)) {

        document.getElementById('errorsum').innerHTML="In Summary Please Enter Only A-Za-z0-9-,_.";

        document.getElementById("divname").style.display='block';

        document.getElementById("imgsum").style.display='block';

        j=false;
        } else{j=true; document.getElementById("divname").style.display='none';             document.getElementById("imgsum").style.display='none';}
}

if(description!="") {

if(!description.match(letters)) {

          document.getElementById('errordesc').innerHTML="In Description Please Enter Only A-Za-z0-9-,_.";

          document.getElementById("divtype").style.display='block';

          document.getElementById("imgdesc").style.display='block';

          j=false;
          else{ j =true; document.getElementById("divtype").style.display='none'; document.getElementById("imgdesc").style.display='none';}

      } 

  }

  return j;
 }

</script>
```